# Django: User not authenticating correctly

Tags: django, authentication

When logging into my app, the user is not authenticating correctly.

Views.py

```
'''

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.urls import reverse
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from users.models import Blog
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

def intro(request):
    return render(request, "intro.html")

def logmein(request):
    return render(request, "logmein.html")

def login(request):
        username1 = request.POST.get('username')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username1, password=password1)
        login(user, request)
        if user.is_authenticated:
                
                return render(request, "users/mainmenu.html")
        else:
                return render(request, "intro.html")

def mainmenu(request):
        
                return render(request, "users/mainmenu.html")
   '''
```

Mainmenu.html

```
'''
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>MainMenu</h2>
Hello, {{ user.username }}
{% endblock %}

'''
```

When mainmenu.html is displayed following login, the user.username is showing as the SuperUser, regardless
of what username and password is used to login.

Comment: Did you login to django admin site in the same browser with superuser. If yes, can you logout from django admin and try this one.

Comment: Thankyou. That helped. Now it is still accepting any user/password combo though. How do I improve this to accept only allowed?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
def login(request):
    username1 = request.POST.get('username')
    password1 = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:    # authentication fails
        messages.error(request, 'error')
        return render(request, "intro.html")

    # login success
    auth_login(request, user)
    messages.success(request, 'success')
    return render(request, "users/mainmenu.html")
```

Comment: Gives same result. Allows any username combination to login, but displays superuser name in mainmenu.html regardless.